# CocoaPods Error (PubNub) with iOS Static Library Project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, pubnub

I'm working on iOS Static Library Project (9.0). I've decided to include PubNub to my Static Library Project. Steps I followed;

1. I've downloaded PubNub sample project and builded.
2. I've copied Framework files (CocoaLumberjack and PubNub) into my Supporting Files folder.
3. I've closed xCode, and created PodFile in project directory.
4. Content of PodFile is as follows:

   **platform :ios, "9.0"**

   **source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'**

   **use_frameworks!**

   **pod "PubNub", "~> 4.0"**
5. After installation i get warning for both Debug and Release says;

[!] The `xxxIOSFramework [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

6. I've opened `.xcworkspace` and saw both my project and Pods project in tree.
7. At this point build gives error `ld: framework not found Pods`

After my re-searches, most says that remove `Pods.framework` which is highlighted in red, and i did.

[image]

8. After removing `Pods.framework`, build continues to give error such as; `ld: -rpath can only be used when creating a dynamic final linked image`
9. I've moved to `Target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags`. `ObjC` was added, and I also added `$(inherited)` but error still exists.

Anyone have any idea about getting `-rpath can only be used when creating a dynamic final linked image` error while adding `Cocoapods` to iOS Static Library Project? I can provide additional information if you need.

Thank you.

Comment: If you added CocoaLumberjack and PubNub dynamic frameworks directly (don't forget to add them to embedded binaries), why you tried to integrate them with CocoaPods later?

Comment: @moonlight I've followed steps at PubNub's Getting Started page. Step by step they say integrate PubNub to a normal project like my steps. With normal project it works. But while trying to integrate with Static Library Project, these errors occurs...

Comment: Getting started describes few integration ways and from your question it looks like you used bot of them at once. If you want to build own static library and integrate PubNub and CocoaLumberjack in it, you should stick to pure CocoaPods approach (remove dynamic frameworks from your project and remove **!use_framewors** if specified in Podfile).

Comment: @moonlight I've tried your suggestion. First; build gave 'library not found for -lPods'. When I remove that file from Frameworks folder, it works fine.. I want to ask; When i type #import "PubNub/PubNub.h" it works fine, but why it doesn't come with intellisense? I have to type as hardcoded. After typing that, i am able to reach classes in PubNub.

Comment: @moonlight btw please write your 2nd comment as an answer. I will Vote Up and Accept as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: It is weird what `#import <PubNub/PubNub.h>` doesn't work for you. Maybe it is something special to the way how CocoaPods integrate other static libraries (result of compilation without !use_frameworks). Also, there is packager plugin for CocoaPods (in case if you will be interested) which will glue multiple static libraries into single file (this approach will require `-all_load` or `-force_load` linker flags to load library code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Getting started* describes few integration ways and from your question it looks like you used bot of them at once.
If you want to build own *static library* and integrate **PubNub** and **CocoaLumberjack** in it, you should stick to pure **CocoaPods** approach.
You need to:

1. ***Remove*** added dynamic **PubNub**  and **CocoaLumberjack** frameworks
2. Remove **!use_framewors** from *Podfile*
3. Clean up a bit (if you have deintegrate plugin installed for CocoaPods you can call it) by removing workspace, Pods folder and Podfile.lock
4. Run `pod install`

This way you should be able to build your own static library with PubNub client code inside.